Why is my shower water discolored when I first run it?
Every morning I turn on newly install shower I get about a cup of golden water. It becomes clear right after I get about a cup of brown water.

Are you on well water?

What are your pipes, what's the water source? Try drawing a glass of water and leaving it on the counter overnight. Does it turn brown?

Did you remove the showerhead for the initial flush of water? If not, you might have some gunk built up in the head itself. Disassemble and clean.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to provide more detail about your situation.

I had a steel "nipple" in my shower system.  The nipple itself was rusting, and the first draw of the day would have rust in it.
It is possible that you are at an earlier stage of the same problem.  Perhaps your nipple hasn't rusted enough to provide enough sediment to be a darker color.  If this is the problem, it will get worse over time as it continues to rust.
The solution in my case was replacing the steel nipple with a brass nipple.
It's also possible that the installer didn't clean the system sufficiently.  As suggested in the comments, disassemble and clean.  If this is the problem, it will get better over time as the water flushes the dirt out.
If you want more help with the disassembly and cleaning, you might post a new question with pictures and identify the model of shower system that was installed.
Note that these problems would be specific to the shower.  If you can get the same result from other fixtures, then you might look at other possibilities.  E.g. if you are on well water, this could simply be a characteristic of the water.  Add more filtering.
